# ListView adapter refuses to populate a listview in a fragment after returning from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

My code is reachable but the adapter just doesnt work. The listview doesnt show and the fragment remains empty.

I re-populate my list at `OnResume`.

my code:

```
public class mylist extends ListFragment {

    public void ToastLoadShout(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private static View View;

    HttpClient client;
    HttpPost httppost;
    HttpGet httpget;
    JSONObject json;
    List<List<String>> items;
    List<item> markers = new ArrayList<item>();

    MobileArrayAdapter adapter;

    ListView list;
    ProgressBar listload;
    Button relist;

    Preferences pref;

    String datadata = "";

    String savedlat="0.0";
    String savedlon="0.0";

    boolean isLoaded=false;
    int index;
    int top;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override 
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // Recreate the adapter from the new feed
        adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(), markers);
        // Set the recreated adapter
        list.setAdapter(adapter); 
        ToastLoadShout("reached here");
        if (!(items==null))
            ToastLoadShout("there are items");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (!isLoaded){
        try {
            pref = new Preferences(getActivity());
            list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            listload = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.listload);
            HashMap<String, String> loc = pref.getData();
            ToastLoadShout(loc.get(Preferences.LAT) + ","
                    + loc.get(Preferences.LON));
            if (loc.get(Preferences.LAT) != null && !loc.get(Preferences.LAT).equals("0.0"))
            {

                if (loc.get(Preferences.LAT) != savedlat && loc.get(Preferences.LON)!=savedlon){
                new Load().execute();
                savedlat=loc.get(Preferences.LAT);
                savedlon=loc.get(Preferences.LON);
                }
            }
            else
                ToastLoadShout("Get Location First.");

            relist = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.relist);
            relist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    HashMap<String, String> loc = pref.getData();
                    ToastLoadShout(loc.get(Preferences.LAT) + ","
                            + loc.get(Preferences.LON));
                    if (loc.get(Preferences.LAT) != null && !loc.get(Preferences.LAT).equals("0.0")){
                        adapter.deleteList();
                        list.destroyDrawingCache();
                        new Load().execute();}
                    else
                        ToastLoadShout("Get Location First.");
                }});

            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                //Check if the last view is visible
                index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v = list.getChildAt(0);
                top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // get selected items
        //String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String selectedValue = markers.get(position).getTitle();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    class Load extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            listload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isLoaded=true;
            ToastLoadShout("preExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                items = DownloadList();
                if (items != null)
                    return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean res) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (res) {
                ArrangePutMarkers();
                adapter=new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(), markers);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                ToastLoadShout("Error");
                ToastLoadShout(datadata);
            }
            listload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ToastLoadShout("PostExecute");
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call notifydatasetchanged method of your adapter after you change its contents. Your OnResume method is assigning an empty data adapter to your listview.

Where are you populating your markers collection?

Also, you can call getListView and setListAdapter methods of the ListFragment class rather than finding the list with findViewById.